# linux sorting of lists by their last parts by using sort command

Tags: linux, sorting, comm

how do I sort lists like the one below using `sort` or any related commands?

```
12.ale.panal.sel.blr.teta.hf.ew.rr.lwq.ors.2018
34.ev.we.ars.lmn.2017
5.lam.bere.meto.belagn.hede.we.e.2020
54.arad.met.kal.sil.tek.br.yz.2005
```

I want to sort them according to the last word which is the year chronologically?
N.B basically something like sort -t. -k-1 although -1 is not allowed. Any command just to address the last part?

Comment: Does this link answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/how-to-numerical-sort-by-last-column

Comment: -k Option : Unix provides the feature of sorting a table on the basis of any column number by using -k option.
Use the -k option to sort on a certain column. For example, use “-k 2” to sort on the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Having a different number of fields in each like makes it a bit more complicated.

This solution uses [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to reverse the fields of each line so it can be sorted by the first column, then returns it to the original order:

```
$ datamash --no-strict -t. reverse < input.txt | sort -t. -k1,1n | datamash --no-strict -t. reverse
54.arad.met.kal.sil.tek.br.yz.2005
34.ev.we.ars.lmn.2017
12.ale.panal.sel.blr.teta.hf.ew.rr.lwq.ors.2018
5.lam.bere.meto.belagn.hede.we.e.2020
```

Or a similar approach using `awk` to copy the last column into a new first column, `sort`, and then `cut` to remove that first column:

```
awk -F. '{ printf "%s\t%s\n", $NF, $0 }' input.txt | sort -k1,1n | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's,([0-9]*$),#\1,' data |  sort -t# -n -k 2,2 | sed 's,#,,'
54.arad.met.kal.sil.tek.br.yz.2005
34.ev.we.ars.lmn.2017
12.ale.panal.sel.blr.teta.hf.ew.rr.lwq.ors.2018
5.lam.bere.meto.belagn.hede.we.e.2020
```

Explanation:

1. Put an artificial delimiter, e.g., #, in front of the sort key field.
2. Sort using the key starting with this delimiter.
3. Remove delimiter.